# Print node tags in html header

Tags: theming, meta-tags

I am trying to print the articles tags in the meta area of the html. I am able to print them, however, they contain all the markup, where as I just need the plain text, comma separated list, much like it prints when using the meta module. 
Here is what I am using.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {  
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
  $node = node_load($node->nid);
   node_build_content($node);
   $variables['field_tags'] = render($node->content['field_tags']);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the content type of field_tags? do you know what the node structure looks like?

Comment: Just article for the content type. 
As far as the structure, it's just title, body, tags, author, etc. Standard stuff. Hope that is what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, I meant field type (text, long text, etc), multi valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your getting html in your output is because your using render(), which is just a wrapper for [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7). Per that function's documentation, it "Renders HTML given a structured array tree."

If you want just something like:
Cats, Dogs, Otters

it would probably be better to just pull out those values, ether by looping through the field_tags array and pulling out the value into an array and then [imploding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your array, or simply looping through and creating a string. So instead of `render()`, use something like:

```
$tags = array();
foreach($node->field_tags['und'] as $tag){
  $tags[] = $tag['value'];
}
$variables['field_tags'] = implode(',', $tags);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking of this as well, however, I am getting a white screen of death when trying the above or a variation of it. Silly question, but can you do a foreach loop in the preprocess function?

Comment: You can. It generally helps if I don't put typos in my code though :) Sorry about that. $node['field_tags'] should be $node->field_tags. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. No more white screen of death :)
Only thing is it's not printing the tags, just 
`"tags": ",,"`
Seems to be not getting the data? Here is what I am using so far: 
`function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {  
if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    $node = node_load($node->nid);
    node_build_content($node);
    $tags = array();
        foreach($node->field_tags['und'] as $tag){
        $tags[] = $tag['value'];
        }
        $variables['field_tags'] = implode(',', $tags);

      }
  }
}
}`

Comment: Sounds like your looping though ok, it's just the value of $tag['value'] isn't set. You might wanna look into installing devel on your site, then trying dsm ($tag) from inside the for loop to see what the values in $tag are. Then switch  ['value'] with the correct index name (it's probably name or something like that if the field is a term reference)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to add more to my comment, but ran out. I was thinking the same, need to find the proper `'value'`.

Comment: @Jance i think you can do it in one line maybe ? does this work ? `$variables['field_tags'] = implode(',', array_column($node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE], 'value'));
`

Comment: Thanks Jance. Got it working by using devel.
Basically, i needed to convert the tid to use the name. So, I used the taxonomy term load function. 
For anyone following, this is what I used. 
`$tags[] = taxonomy_term_load($tag['tid'])->name;`